# Need Help to Display Multiple unserialize value using array_combine and foreach statement

Tags: php

I need help in displaying multiple unserialize values, using array combine or if any other method available.

`array_combine` only accepts 2 parameters but here I have 12 parameters. How can I do it for better understanding. Here is my code.

```
$b_hdest = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hdest'] ) );
$b_hname = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hname'] ) );
$b_hadd = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hadd'] ) );
$b_hphone = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hphone'] ) );
$b_hin = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hin'] ) );
$b_hout = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hout'] ) );
$b_hroom = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hroom'] ) );
$b_hmeal = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hmeal'] ) );
$b_haextra = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_haextra'] ) );
$b_hcextra = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hcextra'] ) );
$b_hspecial = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hspecial'] ) );
$b_hincl = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hincl'] ) );

$hcnt=1;


foreach (array_combine($b_hdest[0], $b_hname[0],$b_hadd[0],$b_hphone[0],$b_hin[0],$b_hout[0],$b_hroom[0],$b_hmeal[0],$b_haextra[0],$b_hcextra[0],$b_hspecial[0],$b_hincl[0]) as $hdest=>$hname=>$hadd=>$hphone=>$hin=>$hout=>$hroom=>$hmeal=>$haextra=>$hcextra=>$hspecial=>$hincl )
{
echo"
<tr><td>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Location : ".$hdest."</td><td>Name : ".$hname."</td><td>Address : ".$hadd."</td><tr>
<tr><td>Phone : ".$hphone."</td><td>CheckIn : ".$hcheckin."</td><td>CheckOut : ".$hout."</td><tr>
<tr><td>Rooms : ".$hroom."</td><td>Meals : ".$hmeal."</td><td>Extra Adult : ".$haextra."</td><tr>
<tr><td>Extra Child : ".$hcextra."</td><td>Special : ".$hspecial."</td><td>Inclusion : ".$hincl."</td><tr>
";
$hcnt++;
}
```

as I am getting error

> Warning: array_combine() expects exactly 2 parameters, 12 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\b2b\view-booking.php on line 84
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\b2b\view-booking.php on line 84

so this means I can't use this method.

I have used the array_merge method but result not as expected.

```
$newArray = array_merge($b_hdest[0], $b_hname[0],$b_hadd[0],$b_hphone[0],$b_hin[0],$b_hout[0],$b_hroom[0],$b_hmeal[0],$b_haextra[0],$b_hcextra[0],$b_hspecial[0],$b_hincl[0]);
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
echo "
<tr><td>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Location : ".$value."</td><td>Name : ".$value."</td><td>Address : ".$value."</td><tr>
<tr><td>Phone : ".$value."</td><td>CheckIn : ".$value."</td><td>CheckOut : ".$value."</td><tr>
<tr><td>Rooms : ".$value."</td><td>Meals : ".$value."</td><td>Extra Adult : ".$value."</td><tr>
<tr><td>Extra Child : ".$value."</td><td>Special : ".$value."</td><td>Inclusion : ".$value."</td><tr>
";
$hcnt++;
}
```

Comment: i have tried to use this method array_merge but, result no as expected

Comment: What is `$hdest=>$hname=>$hadd=>$hphone=>$hin=>$hout`?

Comment: Why you need a loop? You already have values, insert them in html markup.

Comment: sir in short when we use the array_combine($var,$var2 as $ex1=>$ex2) array_combine method

Comment: I don't understand. Everything is written in a manual - you provide __two arrays__ to `array_combine` and it gives you __one array__ as result. Please, write what you really need to do, we will help you to achieve this without `combining`.

Comment: but sir if i don't use any loop which will i get the other value like, in the first loop i get the details of 1st, then in the second loop i get the details of 2nd hotel.

Comment: $b_destinations = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_destinations'] ) );
$b_nights = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_nights'] ) );

foreach (array_combine($b_destinations[0], $b_nights[0]) as $desti=>$nights)
{
echo"
<tr><td>Detination</td><td> ".$desti."</td><td>Nights : ".$nights."</td></tr>";
} this is what i used to show the destinations. the same i used for  hotel details, but array_combine method only accepts 2 parameters and i have  12 parameters. how can i do that.

Comment: sir this is live version of the panel b2b.routemate.in   email : demo@demo.com   password Qwerty123

Comment: after login go diretly to this url http://b2b.routemate.in/view-booking.php?packid=1

Comment: @mega6382 any help sir.

Comment: @Revati don't post password and emails here. I think you should go through this http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

Comment: @Revati Suppose, if there are 7 hotels, b_hdest will contain destination of 7 hotels, right? No less, no more.

Comment: @Revati I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889214/4932070). Check if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes h_hdest will store destinations for 7 hotels, b_hname will store names of the 7 hotels and b_hphone will store the contactno of the 7 hotels and so on for other data also

Keep the code as it is before this. For the rest, follow this.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($b_hdest[0]);$i++){
    echo"
        <tr><td>Hotel Details ".($i+1)."</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Location : ".$b_hdest[0][$i]."</td><td>Name : ".$b_hname[0][$i]."</td><td>Address : ".$b_hadd[0][$i]."</td><tr>
        <tr><td>Phone : ".$b_hphone[0][$i]."</td><td>CheckIn : ".$b_hin[0][$i]."</td><td>CheckOut : ".$b_hout[0][$i]."</td><tr>
        <tr><td>Rooms : ".$b_hroom[0][$i]."</td><td>Meals : ".$b_hmeal[0][$i]."</td><td>Extra Adult : ".$b_haextra[0][$i]."</td><tr>
        <tr><td>Extra Child : ".$b_hcextra[0][$i]."</td><td>Special : ".$b_hspecial[0][$i]."</td><td>Inclusion : ".$b_hincl[0][$i]."</td><tr>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Kerala Dest1 [1] => Allepy Dest2 ) )

Answer (score 0):

If all your `$b_` values are arrays then iterate over one array and get according keys from others:

```
$b_hdest = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hdest'] ) );
$b_hname = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hname'] ) );
$b_hadd = unserialize( base64_decode( $rs['b_hadd'] ) );
// more $b_ variables

foreach ($b_hdest as $key => $value) {
    // $key is a current index.
    echo $value, ', ', $b_hname[$key], ', ', $b_hadd[$key], '<br />';
}
```

Comment: hello sir, i am getting Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\b2b\view-booking.php on line 97
Array.Array.Array    using your answer